# SQL Max Function not returning correct max value

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL max function not giving the correct result for

```
select max (liri_appid) from idea_interface;
```

result is : 90802 but I know  it's having max value as 15454545

The same problem facing when I am running the order by clause. Results are coming as

```
 1
 13
 2
 23
 4
 5
 6
 69
 777
 9
```

Not sure why.

Comment: share your table structure and sample data

Comment: LIRI_ID   NUMBER
LIRI_APPID  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
LIRI_CUST_ID_N  NUMBER(15,0)
LIRI_PROD_CODE  VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)


1 70201801 70201801 A
2 1408001  14080002 A
3 1408002  148003 A
4 1480003  1480003 A
5 1480004  1480004 P
6 1480006  1480006 A
7 1480006  1480007 A
8 1480007  148000701 A
9 1480007  148000702 A
16 210918002 210918002 U
23 25061812 25061812 P
24 25061817 25061817 P
25 25061822 25061822 P
26 25061824 25061824 P
27 25061826 25061826 P
28 26061803 26061803 P
29 26061804 26061804 P
30 26061805 26061805 P
31 26061808 26061808 P
32 26061809 26061809 P

Comment: For future reference please **edit your question** to include clarifications or further information. Code and data are particularly hard to read in comments, due to the lack of formatting.

Comment: Thanks  i got the problem problem is data type

Answer (score 6):

> LIRI_APPID    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)

`liri_appid` is defined as `varchar2`. That means it uses string semantics. ASCII value of `9` is higher than ASCII value of `1` so `'90802'` is larger than  '`15454545'`.

For the same reason `'13'` is lower than `'2'` hence your ordering oddity.

Workaround is

```
 select max (to_number( (liri_appid))
 from idea_interface;
```

and

```
order by to_number( (liri_appid) asc
```

Proper solution is to change your data model so `liri_appid` is defined as a number. Using the correct datatype is always the best policy.

Answer (score 3):

Your field type is definitely a `Text` type which it order them by their `ASCII`code value like below:

> 1, 12, 13, 2, 20, 21, ...

Change the field type to a number typed field.